# Programmatically import products and set custom attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, import, dropdown-attribute

I'm importing my products from a .csv and I have some trouble setting the custom attribute values. The attribute types are dropdown since they are used for configurable products.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

include_once "../app/Mage.php";
include_once "../downloader/Maged/Controller.php";

Mage::init();

// Set the store id
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$Simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

try{
    $Simpleproduct
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
    ->setAttributeSetId(4) 
    ->setTypeId('simple') 
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
    ->setSku('testsku61') //SKU
    ->setName('test product21')
    ->setWeight(4.0000) 
    ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22 
    ->setDescription('This is a long description')
    ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
    ->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,     
        'manage_stock'=>1, 
        'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 999 //qty
         )
     )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 11))
     $data=array(
       'afmeting' => '180 x 100',
       'afwerkingblad '=> 'Havanna',
       'afwerkingonderstel '=> 'Blank'); 

//Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($Simpleproduct->getId()), $data, $storeId); // Found out this is only for updating
  $Simpleproduct->setData($data); // this doesn't work either
  if($Simpleproduct->save()){
    echo "test";
  }
  }catch(Exception $e){
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    echo $e;
    echo "faal";
  }
```

Whenever I run the code I get the following error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db90927_magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks like there are PHP syntax errors. For example:

```
   ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 11))
 $data=array(
   'afmeting' => '180 x 100',
   'afwerkingblad '=> 'Havanna',
   'afwerkingonderstel '=> 'Blank');
```

Also, when you call

```
$Simpleproduct->setData($data);
```

you're replacing the data on the product instance. I think you want to do:

```
$Simpleproduct->addData($data);
```

As for the SQL exception, it's a foreign key exception to the eav_attribute_set table. Can you double check that

```
->setAttributeSetId(4)
```

there's an attribute set with id 4?